# Create an auto reference number for every magento order id (for courier billing purposes )

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, shipment, eav-attributes

I want to create a reference number for every Magento order that comes, which I want to use for courier billing purposes. A reference number will be additional security for me for courier billing purposes. I want to use both order number and reference on shipping slip.

Comment: can any one please send me the code for this ..Please guys help

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why this redundancy is needed but you may identify an order by both **order id** or **order increment id**. They are different.

Besides from that an additional attribute for order entity can always be created with an install/setup script

```
$attribute  = array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'backend_type'  => 'text',
        'frontend_input' => 'text',
        'is_user_defined' => true,
        'label'         => 'reference',
        'visible'       => true,
        'required'      => false,
        'user_defined'  => false,   
        'searchable'    => false,
        'filterable'    => false,
        'comparable'    => false,
        'default'       => ''
);
$installer->addAttribute('order', 'custom_reference', $attribute);
```

or is the question more about dragging attribute data over to a shipping slip?